# Grouping date based on week | Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### List Image

[image: List Image]

### Result That I Hope

[image: Result That I Hope]

I need to figure how to group list of date.

Date Formula : "mm/dd/yyyy"

i've tried using :
1. `=A1 + 7` . it returns 43113
2. `=A1 + WEEKDAY(A1;1)` . it returns 43113

Is there any formula to calculate date?

I have an logic for grouping

`=IF(A2<(A2+WEEKDAY(A2;1))`;Return the number of the first week;Nested IF)

Target :
there are 5 groups

- june 1-7
- june 8-14
- june 15-21
- june 22-28
- june 29-5

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly is the issue, but I'm going to assume that you need a date instead of the 43113 ? That can be solved with simple formatting

Comment: Hi M.Douda, Basically I need to group list of dates that been generated from transaction. for report purpose, i need to report with weekly format, so i need to group list of this data to weekly format.

Comment: I think it'd be easier if you included a picture with example data that shows your current results and desired results if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: let me add the detail at my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there are no dates ouside of the desired groups, this is the correct nested IF formula for all data.

`=IF(AND(I7>=43252;I7<=43258);1;IF(AND(I7>=43259;I7<=43265);2;IF(AND(I7>=43266;I7<=43272);3;IF(AND(I7>=43273;I7<=43279);4;5))))`

Comment: can you explain where does 43252 and 43258 number comes from ? it works btw. thanks :)

Comment: Those are number values for the dates, you can check that by writing the numbers down then changing the format to date